# How do I change the format of a date/time string in perl? (specific question)

Tags: perl, string, datetime, formatting

I have an example string parsed from a log file in the following format:

"Mon Apr 25 17:47:19 2011"

and I want it to look like

"Mon Apr 25 05:47PM 2011"

How would I do this in general? (i.e. it's not going to be the same string every time of course).

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in doubt, it's usually a good bet to go with [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime). In this case you could:

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
);

my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime('Mon Apr 25 17:47:19 2011');
print $dt->strftime('%a %b %d %I:%M%p %Y'), "\n";
```

If you need information on the patterns, see [the strftime docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html) or the similar section in the [DateTime Manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime#strftime_Patterns).

You could also work this using the `strftime` function in [POSIX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POSIX) and the `strptime` function in [POSIX::strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POSIX%3a%3astrptime), but the interfaces are less enjoyable.

Comment: That's perfect! Exactly what I needed to do. Thank you so much!